# how to distingish between local and static variables of same name

Tags: c#, static, scope

example to illustrate :

```
public class Something
{
    private static int number;

    static Something()
    {
        int number = 10;

        // Syntax to distingish between local variable and static variable ?
    }
}
```

Inside the static constructor, is there a syntax that can be used to distinguish between the local variable called "number", and the static variable of the same name ?

Comment: Removed the `[distinguishedname]` tag because it shouldn't really exist to begin with.  Added `[scope]` instead

Comment: Or you could use a different name (or naming convention) for the static variable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Something.number
```

Obvious, no?.

Comment: And if your class isn't static, you can be all like:

    class Something
    {
        int number;

        public Something()
        {
            int number = 10;

            this.number = number + 1;
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Unqualified will get you the inner-most scoped variable (the local variable):

```
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

> 10

You can qualify your usage to get the static variable:

```
Console.WriteLine(Something.number);
```

> 0